# image upload to a .NET server

Tags: image, upload

This is the code I'm using. How do I specify the .NET server address which should receive the image?

```
    var form = document.forms.namedItem("fileinfo");
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {

    var oOutput = document.querySelector("div"),
    oData = new FormData(form);

    oData.append("CustomField", "extra data");

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("POST", "abcd", true);
    oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
    if (oReq.status == 200) {
    oOutput.innerHTML = "Uploaded!";
    } 
    else 
    {
    oOutput.innerHTML = "Error " + oReq.status + " occurred when trying to                  upload your file.<br \/>";
    }
    };

      oReq.send(oData);
      ev.preventDefault();
    }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a generic handler. In *ProcessRequest* event, put this base code

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    HttpPostedFile doc = context.Request.Files[0];

    //Your code....

    doc.SaveAs("YOUR_PATH" + "/" + doc.FileName);
}
```

The ajax post should go to this resource...

Comment: This is for the server to return the result right? How do I give the servers address in my code, so I can send a request to it?